# Can I control the architecture (32bit vs 64bit) when building a pyinstaller executable?

Tags: python, windows, usb, 32bit-64bit, pyinstaller

**Short Question**
Is there any way to control / guarantee the architecture (32bit vs 64bit) when building a pyinstaller executable?

**Background**
I migrated from py2exe to pyinstaller because of the lack of 64bit support along with a host of small things that I am having a hard time looking past.  So on that note, I would prefer *not* to go back to it.  I have developed two applications using Python 2.7 64bit and am having performance issues when running on them 32 bit machines.

The first is a simple wxPython GUI (version 2.9) and connects to a windows DLL file for a USB driver.  This one seems pretty "safe" to run as 32 bit because there are no modules which are 64bit only.  However this application when running on 32bit Windows XP has horrible performance issues when talking to the USB device.

The second application is much larger and I have not attempted to build and run yet because of the fear of architecture issues.  This application has a number 64bit only modules (psycopg2 for one) used in it.  I would like to stay away from trying to build this if it *impossible* to run as a 32bit executable.

**Current Thoughts**
I feel that this might be possible (if the modules have 32bit support) by running the build.py with Python forced in 32bit mode.  Does this make any sense?

**Update**
I had several breakthroughs on the first program I was building.  It turns out the performance issues was solely based on the speed of the two machines.  My dev machine had enough power to poll the USB device fast enough and the much slower test platform (Windows XP) did not.

I fixed this issue by modifying the way I polled the USB port.  Now that this was fixed, I could run the exe on both systems.  A new problem had come up when trying to build the executable as a single file.  When running pyinstaller's Build.py, it pulls in all of the required DLL's the app needs to run.  This seemed to work great at first, but when I tried to run the single exe that I built on Windows 7 64bit, it would not run on Windows XP because the USB dongle's DLL was not recognized as a valid DLL.

In order to get the single exe to run on both systems, I first tried to remove the DLL from the .spec file (which appears to be a python script).  It was convenient because I was able to modify the list of includes prior to the build command with ordinary python list modifiers.  My hope was that if the DLL was not found in the exe's temp directory it would find it on the system PATH.  While this approach *might* work, I could not get it to run without throwing lots of errors.

My second attempt was to build the application on the Windows XP machine (leaving the DLL embedded) in hope that the Win XP DLL would work in Windows 7.  Success!  This configuration works well; however I do strongly believe that this not the best solution as it depends solely on the older DLL running on a newer OS.

Comment: I know that you have a working solution, but did you try installing 32-bit Python on the Win7 machine and using that to run build.py? You'd have to install all the 32-bit dependencies as well, but that should grab the correct 32-bit DLLs. (On the other hand, it may not work if you need to support XP.)

Comment: @Velociraptors: The only DLL that it seemed to grab that I didn't want it to was the DLL for the USB dongle.  This device's software is 32bit only, so I am going out on a limb and guessing that the driver was 32bit as well.  So in this case I think it was a 7 vs XP driver incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 16):

Pyinstaller produces a binary depending from the python you used to build it. So if you use python 2.7 64 bit it is not possible, as far as I know, to produce a 32 bit executable. This is because Pyinstaller archives all modules and their dependencies (dlls, pyds etc..) which are 64 bit due to the python install.

As already said it is better, because of cross compatibility issues, to build 32-bit binaries.
Probably you can specify more your question.

Answer (score 9):

If you are building an application and it runs fine on 32-bit Windows, there is no need to create a 64-bit version. Just create a 32-bit version and run it on both architectures. What is what WOW64 is for.

If you need to use a library or feature which is 64-bit only, just build a 64-bit version. There is no point in building a 32-bit version if the feature is 64-bit only.

The only reason to build a 64-bit and 32-bit version both, is to take advantage of increased address space of 64-bit windows. I.e. if you intend to allocate more than 1 or 2 GB of memory. An example might be an image editing application, or a data manipulation application. Then you can run on 32-bit platforms within the constraints of the platform but edit larger images or larger quantities of data on 64-bit platforms.

IOW, for your case follow the suggestion of @Velociraptors and build in 32-bit python if you are building a 32-bit exe.

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay in a response.  I agree with you in the fact that if 64 bit's not needed, don't use it.  However if I'm running Windows 7 64 bit and 64 bit Python, how can I create a 32-bit version?  That's the real question here.

Comment: @AdamLewis, Install 32-bit python as well, and have your build-script generate both executables.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to build a 32-bit  application on a 64-bit system and hav only a 64-bit version of Python installed, you have to install also a 32-bit version of Python. Then you have to instal pyinstaller to that 32-bit Python version  as follows:

```
path/to/32-bit/python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

After that  you  can run the 32-bit version of pyinstaller, and thus build a 32-bit application, like this:

```
path/to/32-bit/pyinstaller your-app.py
```

On Windows 10, `pyinstaller.exe` is located at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe`.

As you can see, the architecture of the application you want to build depends on the Python and pyinstaller versions which you are going to use to build that application. This way you can also, for instance, build an application from a Python version 2.x if you have it installed on the system.