# Convert script to executable, python not in registry

Tags: python, windows, exe

I am trying to convert a python script to an executable file.

I have tried cxFreeze and py2exe, but both told me that Python27 are not in the registry. I found several other questions that tell me to go to regedit and find the python folder, but it is not there. I tried going to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software and Python27 was not there.

Do I need to add it there to run the installer for cxFreeze or py2exe or is there another way?

Comment: How did you install python?

Comment: install pyinstaller then try pyinstaller filename.py -F in command prompt in the directory where the python file is available

Comment: I installed it at the python.org download page for 2.7.8. I used the x86 64-bit .msi installer. I use the installer for the py2exe or cxFreeze and I get as far as opening it and pressing next, then it says I have an error. On the next page it asks for the Python directory and I can't type text into it.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like [PyInstaller](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller) package python scripts with the python run-time interpreter into standalone Windows applications. Installation of python (2.7.x) and all required python libraries [is a prerequisite](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script).

My suggestion is to install the latest Python 2.7 from this location: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/. Make sure to choose the [correct architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155866/can-i-control-the-architecture-32bit-vs-64bit-when-building-a-pyinstaller-exec), apparently 32-bit is the easiest to get working.

Comment: I have Python installed. I have version 2.7.8 if you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Apparently I accidentally installed 32-bit Python on a 64-bit machine. So I have to use the 32-bit installer because it installs the registry key in a different place. Thanks for the help anyways.