# Executable for windows platform for python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze, py2app

Guys I know this question was asked here before. But all those questions are a bit old and not useful right now.

I have a set of tools that I think would help me convert my web ui app to `.exe` file.

I used pyinstaller and had difficulties installing it on cross windows OS. It was build on 10 but didn't work on 7.

So is there a single solution for a single exe file creator for just windows ? It should work on both 64 and 32 bit, and also in windows 7,8 and 10.

Also I have another doubt will the exe file build on windows 10 64bit work in 32 bit ? I didn't get any 32 bit system but maybe someone who downloads the app uses it, didn't find anything that speaking about 32 and 64 bit in pyinstaller page either.

So my 3 questions are:
1) Is there a possibility to build a single exe file for whole windows platform currently?

2) does pyinstaller support 64 and 32 bit if it was build on 64 bit windows ?

3) Downgrading to python 3.4 a good idea for using py2exe ?

Comment: To stand any chance I’d expect you’ll have to use 32-bit Python and matching pyinstaller. PyInstaller doesn’t claim any cross-bitness capability.

Comment: E.g. see one of those old questions you refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155866/can-i-control-the-architecture-32bit-vs-64bit-when-building-a-pyinstaller-exec#10328518

Comment: And did you read the (current, recent) PyInstaller documentatione.g. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html which says in reference to the user (you) needing to include approapriate vcredist “If you think PyInstaller should do this by itself, please help improving PyInstaller.”