# How to run application made with python 64bit in windows 32bit without installing python 32bit?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, 32-bit

I made an application GUI with database with python 3.7.3 64bit and i exported it with pyinstaller but when i run it in windows 7 32bit it shows an error.

does any one have solution to how to convert app 64bit to 32bit without installing the 32bit version of python ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I control the architecture (32bit vs 64bit) when building a pyinstaller executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155866/can-i-control-the-architecture-32bit-vs-64bit-when-building-a-pyinstaller-exec)

Comment: The consensus, as reflected in the duplicate question I tagged, is that you need a 32-bit installation of Python and pyinstaller in order to create 32-bit executables. Apparently there is no way to cross-compile.

Comment: Please include the errors you receive in your questions.